# do piano strings have diffrent string types

Tags: piano

so I was wondering about the strings they use on pianos and was wondering if they used the same type of strings as any strung instrument do they have different types of strings like steel or Nickel.for a different sound

Comment: I like Ernie Ball, Skinny Top Heavy Bottom on my pianos... gives some punch on the lows & makes the highs easier to bend ;-) [sorry, couldn't resist... back to being serious]

Comment: You do know that 5 minutes with Google will give you more info on piano strings than you could possibly want?

Answer (score 2):

From http://bleespiano.com/services/replacing-broken-strings/

> There are two kinds of strings on a piano: Bass string and treble strings. Bass strings are steel strings wrapped with copper.
>
> Treble strings are also steel and come in different diameters, but are not wrapped

Piano strings are at much higher tension than most other instruments (around 160 pounds per string) hence the metal frame of a concert grand, which has to withstand around 30 tons of pressure, and close to 20 tons for an upright, for example, so steel is the only material used for the core of bass strings, or for the treble strings.